# Applications in a GridView in Android

Tags: android, gridview

I am developing an app where I'll put the applications (only specific applications) in a Grid View, however I don't know if my codes is the right way to populate the Grid View.  The mainActivity is just like a container of applications. Now, what I want to know are:

1. How can I populate my grid view with selected application only?
2. How can I launch each and every application properly?

**MainActivity.java**

```
 ...   

    GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1);

    Resources res = getResources();
    List<AppInfo> listAppInfo = new ArrayList<AppInfo>();
    listAppInfo.add(new AppInfo(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.img_sample1), "Application 1"));

    gridView.setAdapter(new AppInfoAdapter(this, listAppInfo));

    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(mItemClickListener);

}

private OnItemClickListener mItemClickListener = new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
        ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder)view.getTag();
        if(holder == null) {
            return;
        }
        Intent LaunchIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        LaunchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.example.sampleproject");
        LaunchIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS);
        context.startActivity(LaunchIntent);
    }
};
```

**AppInfoAdapter.java**

```
public class AppInfoAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context mContext;
private List<AppInfo> mListAppInfo;

public AppInfoAdapter(Context context, List<AppInfo> list) {
    mContext = context;
    mListAppInfo = list;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mListAppInfo.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return mListAppInfo.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    AppInfo entry = mListAppInfo.get(position);
    ViewHolder holder = null;

    if(convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_appinfo, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.ivIcon = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_image);
        holder.tvName = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_text);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else {
        holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.ivIcon.setImageBitmap(entry.getIcon());
    holder.tvName.setText(entry.getName());

    return convertView;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    ImageView ivIcon;
    TextView tvName;
}
```

Comment: Pass the selected list to your adapter not whole of the list. and for get the position of selected item OnItemClickListener and get the package name of that position from the list.

Comment: Hi @Ankit, can you show me how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  ArrayList<String> Listapp = new ArrayList<String>();
  ArrayList<String> Listapp1 = new ArrayList<String>();
  final PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
  // get a list of installed apps.
/*
      List<ApplicationInfo> packages = pm.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
                    for (ApplicationInfo packageInfo : packages) {
                            Listapp1.add(packageInfo.packageName);
                            Listapp.add((String) packageInfo.loadLabel(pm));
                    }*/
//you can add app as you like if know package name.
//You can add package name to Listapp1 
//You can add name to Listapp 

        gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid);
            MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(this);
            gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
            gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int pos, long arg3) {
                    packageManager = getPackageManager();
                    Intent intent = packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(Listapp1.get(pos));
                    if (null != intent) {
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                }

            });
```

MyAdapter Class:

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private Bitmap[] bitmap = new Bitmap[AppList1.size()];
        private Context context;
        private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
        MyAdapter(Context c) {
            context = c;
            layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            // init dummy bitmap,
            // using R.drawable.icon for all items
            for (int i = 0; i < Listapp1.size(); i++) {
                try {
                    PackageManager manager = context.getPackageManager();
                    Drawable appIcon;
                    appIcon = manager.getApplicationIcon(Listapp1.get(i));
                    bitmap[i] = ((BitmapDrawable)appIcon).getBitmap();
                } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
                    bitmap[i] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.logo);
                }

            }
        }
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return bitmap.length;
        }
        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return bitmap[position];
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View grid;
            if (convertView == null) {
                grid = new View(context);
                grid = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item, null);
            } else {
                grid = (View) convertView;
            }

            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) grid.findViewById(R.id.image);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap[position]);
            TextView textView = (TextView) grid.findViewById(R.id.text);
            textView.setText(Listapp.get(position));

            return grid;
        }

    }
```

R.layout.item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="50px"
        android:layout_height="50px"
        android:layout_marginRight="10px" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5px"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10sp"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I'd like only to get specific application, NOT ALL OF IT.

Comment: are you would like to choose some app.?

Comment: I'd like to load 1-3 apps only in the GridView

Comment: you can add app as you like if know package name.
You can add package name to Listapp1 
You can add name to Listapp 

and check code above